# save object in asp mvc (Session ,...)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, instagram, instagram-api

I am using "InstaSHarper"
and its a private API for Instagram 
a want to login and save that login state;
i can save that in Session ;but its not for long time after SessionEnd we should be login again and its cause of block by Instagram
an example code as U can see i save that in Session:

```
        IInstaApi _instaApi;
        var userSession = new UserSessionData
        {
            UserName = instauserWork.InstaUser.UserName,
            Password = instauserWork.InstaUser.PassWord
        };
        _instaApi = (InstaApi)new InstaApiBuilder()
            .SetUser(userSession)
            .Build();
                    var logInResult = await _instaApi.LoginAsync();
                    if (logInResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        "Session["instauser" + iu.Id.ToString()] = _instaApi;"
                     }
```

and by the way i cant save it in Catch or Cookies or db
because _instaApi contain this :

```
    private readonly AndroidDevice _deviceInfo;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly HttpClientHandler _httpHandler;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ApiRequestMessage _requestMessage;
    private readonly UserSessionData _user;
```

any idea how can i save that class(i mean this "IInstaApi _instaApi" that contain above property)

Comment: Serialize it somewhere else?

Comment: no Serialize, _instaApi  is class that contain those U can see above ,i cant Serialize,can i?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use static variable _instaApi in your server.